# A sequence of perfect and never-dense subsets in $\mathbb{R}$ whose union is measurable of measure 1?

Tags: measure-theory

How can I construct a sequence  $(K_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of perfect and nowhere dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ whose union is measurable of measure $1$? also how can I prove that there cannot be a perfect and nowhere dens subset in $[0, 1]$ of measure equal to $1$?

---

**My attempt:**

1. We need to construct a sequence $(K_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ where each $K_{i}$ is a **perfect set** and **nowhere dense** subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} K_{n}$ is measurable and $\displaystyle \mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}K_{n} \right)=1$.
   Let $\alpha \in (0,1)$, we remove from the center $[0,1]$ a open interval of length $\alpha/2$, for example $$J_{1}(1)=\left( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{\alpha}{2^{2}},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{2^{2}}\right)$$and denote $C_{1}(\alpha)$ the union of the closed intervals that remain, this is, $$C_{1}(\alpha)=\left[0, \frac{1}{2}-\frac{\alpha}{2^{\alpha}}\right]\cup \left[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\alpha}{2^{2}},1\right]$$
   Continuing indefinitely with this elimination of open intervals, we can see that we obtain a decreasing sequence of compact sets $(C_{n}(\alpha))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ where each is the disjoint union of $2^{n}$ closed and bounded intervals.
   Let $$_{\alpha}K=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}(\alpha)$$
   So, we can see that $_{\alpha}K$ is compact, perfect and nowhere dense set.
   Also, I could prove that $\mu(_{\alpha}K)=1-\alpha>0$

Also, for all $n\geq 2$ let $a_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$ so, we can see that $$\mu(_{\alpha_{n}K})=1-\frac{1}{n}$$

but, can I  say as like to $$_{\alpha_{n}}K=\bigcup_{n=2}^{\infty} {_{\alpha}K_{n}}?$$

---

I'm just studying measure theory so I try to understand each concept well

It would be great if someone could write a detailed solution or point me out the steps to take. I have read the comments and more or less I have tried to do that, but I don't know how: 1) to form the union of my construction, 2) how to prove that the union measure gives 1, 3) prove that there is no such set.

Comment: Google "Fat Cantor set".

Comment: Yes, I was reading that hint, but I don't understand how can I use that for to approach for to solve theses problems.Thank you so much.

Comment: The union of a sequence of closed sets is a Borel set, so it will automatically be measurable. What you need to do is construct a nowhere dense perfect subset of $[0,1]$ of measure greater than $1-\frac1n$. If you can constuct a dense open set of measure less than $\frac1n$ then its complement in $[0,1]$ (after you remove the isolated points) will do.

Comment: Find $A_n$ perfect, nowhere-dense, and of measure exceeding $1-1/n$.

Comment: Hint for your last question: an open set can't have measure zero.

Comment: By surrounding each rational with a short open interval, you can get a dense open set with measure less that $\varepsilon$. Take care that no two intervals abut, so the complement won't have any isolated points.

Comment: Try $K_n = [0,1] \quad\backslash \bigcup\limits_{0<a<2^b}\left(\frac{a}{2^b} - \frac{1}{n2^{2b}}, \frac{a}{2^b} + \frac{1}{n2^{2b}}\right)$ with $a$ and $b$ ranging over the integers.  Then the measure of $K_n$ is between $1-\frac1n$ and $1-\frac1{2n}$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, can you review my edit in the post?. I added my new approach, I don't understand well this topicm, so really I'm trying to learn well.